# Regexp between first period and whitespace until next period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I know this should probably be easier than I am making this. Sorry if this is an easy question.

I am using regular expressions for my Rails application (do regular expressions change based on the language?) and I want to take a phrase like this: "I am not familiar with RegExp. Hopefully SO will help me out here. This is a third sentence which should not be included." and have RegExp return "Hopefully SO will help me out here" (without the period and whitespace at the beginning and without the period at the end)

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
^([^(.)\s]+)

([^\.\s]+)

((\.\s))

\.\s+\K.+
```

I really don't know what to do here. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Use `\.\s+(.+)` and grab Group 1 value. [See a sample demo](https://regex101.com/r/lCJOda/1) for PHP where you may even use `\K`

Comment: First period and whitespace `\.\s` up until next period `[^.]*\.` Or, `\.\s\K[^.]*(?=\.)`

Comment: sln, how do I make it so that the regular expression only includes everything after the whitespace?

Comment: Use `\K` construct. There are other possibilities, depends on how general/strict you want to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments that enabled me to solve this problem. The final solution ended up being the following:

```
\A[^.]*\.\s\K[^.]*(?=\.)
```

Translation:

`\A` declares start of string

`[^.]*` says that you can have as many characters or whitespaces (as long as they are before the first period)

`\.\s` finds the first period and whitespace

`\K` then includes everything after that in the expression

`[^.]*` includes every character or whitespace until the first period

`(?=\.)` states to stop after the first period following the beginning (marked by \K)

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Why not just `s[/\.\s+([^.]+)/, 1]`?

Comment: Wiktor, when I use rubular.com, this solution doesn't seem to work. Not sure why there are forward slashes? Might just be difference in language? I am not sure. I appreciate your help though! Your suggestion about \K really helped!

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It captures the second sentence as "Hopefully SO will help me out here".

```
\.\s*([\w\s]*)\.
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Posted the final answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
s[/\.\s+([^.]+)\./, 1]
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/ffISPe), output: `Hopefully SO will help me out here`
.

Here, the `[/regex/, 1]` syntax means you want to apply the `regex` to the `s` string and only output the contents of Group 1. Thus, you do not really need a [`\K` *match reset operator*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html), but surely you may use

```
s[/\.\s+\K[^.]+(?=\.)/]
```

that will yield the same result.